# Format data as an excel table using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I should format some data in an excel sheet as an excel table using powershell (manually it means selecting a range on a sheet and click on "format as a table"). Probably I need to use COM, but I don't know the syntax for a similar command. Is there anybody who has a script to take as an example or the link to a good COM guide where I could find something helpful?
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642193/9898643). That uses a CSV file as input, but it shows how easy it can be using module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) and also explains how to do it using Excel as COM object.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is 2 months old, but this is the line I use to convert my data to a table:

```
Export-Excel -Path "Path\To\Excel.xlsx" -TableName CreateYourTableNameHere -AutoSize
```